# Is it possible to add an alternate coloring for questions with 'community upvoted' answers?

Tags: feature-request, design

My original question was the common "accept" feature. But having seen the reasons against it I altered it to be more consistent with the desires laid out in the below meta question.

I found these questions:

- [Is it possible for this answer to be marked as accepted?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2322/is-it-possible-for-this-answer-to-be-marked-as-accepted)
- [New community "accept" privilege](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/new-community-accept-privilege)

which both explain the reason for why an accept feature has been rejected overall in stack overflow.

- What the community thinks is the right answer, indicated by having the highest number of votes.

The checkmark puts a green box around the number of answers to indicate the question was answered according to the original asker. But there is no indication that any of the answers are upvoted at all. If the community is 'accepting' an answer through upvotes I feel it should be shown at a glance as well.

This question

[When does building extra buildings start to give diminishing returns?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185964/after-which-point-is-building-extra-buildings-gives-diminishing-return)

appears exactly the same as this one

[Where do knights train fastest in The Settlers?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/107459/where-do-knights-train-fastest-in-the-settlers)

in search results despite the first having an answer with 12 upvotes and the second having an answer with 0 because both are missing the elusive accepted answer checkmark.

So I am just proposing to put a blue (or some other color) box around questions with highly upvoted but no officially accepted answer. The blue box would then turn green if an answer is ever accepted by the original user. This way people can know that the community essentially selected an answer.